# How to serialize and restore the list of functions?

Tags: java, function, serialization

I'd like to create list of functions, which I'll be able to run in the future.

First listing:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class ExampleF implements Serializable{
    interface Executable extends Serializable{  void execute(); }
    ArrayList<Executable> alFunc = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ExampleF     ex1 =new ExampleF();
        Executable exec1 =new Executable() {
            @Override
            public void execute() { System.out.println("exec func1"); }
        };
        Executable exec2 =new Executable() {
            @Override
            public void execute() { System.out.println("exec func2"); }
        };

        ex1.alFunc.add(exec1);
        ex1.alFunc.add(exec2);
        ex1.alFunc.get(0).execute();
        ex1.alFunc.get(1).execute();

        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("data1.dat"));
        oos.writeObject(ex1);
        oos.close();

        System.out.println("after loading:");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("data1.dat"));
        ExampleF ex2 = (ExampleF) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
        ex2.alFunc.get(0).execute();
        ex2.alFunc.get(1).execute();
    }
}
```

Worked fine, output was:

```
exec func1
exec func2
after loading:
exec func1
exec func2
```

But when I try use **clear loading** by using **only serialization info** I get `ClassNotFoundException for ExampleF$1`:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class ExampleF implements Serializable{
    interface Executable extends Serializable{  void execute(); }
    ArrayList<Executable> alFunc = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("data1.dat"));
        ExampleF ex2 = (ExampleF) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
        ex2.alFunc.get(0).execute();
        ex2.alFunc.get(1).execute();
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

- Create multiple lists of necessary functions
- Serialize
- Use it in the future only after downloading the required files with using only execute().

Perhaps exists other ways to store ArrayList of functions?
P.S. I use Java7 (If it necessary can upgrate to Java8).

Answer (score 2):

You get this issue because exec1 and exec2 are anonymous class that you create within the scope of the main method. You have to convert them into normal class, static nested class or at least they should be defined as static variables like below:

```
public class ExampleF implements Serializable {
    interface Executable extends Serializable {  void execute(); }
    ArrayList<Executable> alFunc = new ArrayList<>();
    private static Executable exec1 =new Executable() {
        @Override
        public void execute() { System.out.println("exec func1"); }
    };
    private static Executable exec2 =new Executable() {
        @Override
        public void execute() { System.out.println("exec func2"); }
    };
...
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it. However, in this case  I should be able to describe all private static inner class in second example (with deserialization and function run code only). I'd like to have compact code (without describing of functions), I'd like get code of fucntions from serialization file. Or I get local class incompatible exception : stream classdesc serialVersionUID = ....

Comment: @Joysi what you want to do is much more complex then, you will need to serialize the class content and rely on a specific class loader to load your class. Maybe the simplest way for you would be to use RMI as it does it out of the box, check this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/

Comment: I understand that there is no standard way to **serialize** Java byte code of functions with the possibility of further deserialization.as executable items of ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this blog-post. You are using anonymous classes - http://programmeit.blogspot.in/2012/08/why-anonymous-classes-and-inner-classes.html

If you take a close look in example #1and #2, you will find that the anonymous class present in #1 is not present in #2. In such scenario, JVM will not be able to find that class.

Comment: Thank you. I know about anonymous functions. I do not know how to get around it and decide generally. What is there another way to deserialize a list of functions without any descriptions (in the classes etc.)? To download from the serialized file ready code.

Comment: I'd like to maintain unchanged the second part of the code:  

    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("data1.dat"));
    ExampleF ex2 = (ExampleF) ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
    ex2.alFunc.get(0).execute();
    ex2.alFunc.get(1).execute();

Comment: So that's the problem. The identity of anonymous classes is tied up with the parent class where that are declared. Now if you want to have those classes still available, you will need to get those classes in the classpath somehow. May be writing your own class loader that loads the selective classes from different location than others.